# ng2-ckeditor "CKEDITOR" within my form not Working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ckeditor

I want to use `CKEDITOR` in `my form`.
I pass the model to `CKEDITOR` but nothing happens, I did the same thing without using the `form` and it works correctly, What is the reason?

I have uploaded the codes and images below,

please guide me!

Thanks,

`package.json`

```
//...
  "@angular/core": "^11.2.2",
  "@angular/forms": "^11.2.2",
  "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.3.4",
//...
```

`index.html`

```xml
<!--...-->
<form *ngIf="active" #ticketForm="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" autocomplete="off">
  <ckeditor #ticket_MessageOfTicket="ngModel"
  [(ngModel)]="this.messageOfTicket"
  [config]="config"></ckeditor>
  <!--...-->
</form>
<!--...-->
```

`index.component.ts`

```
//...
 config:any = {
     contentsLangDirection: 'rtl',
  }

//...
  ngOnInit(): void {
       this.messageOfTicket="<p>Hello <strong>world !</strong></p>";
   }
//...
```

[image]